# Will a flying droplet-siphon work in vacuum?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

So I recently learned a couple things about siphons:

1. Siphons work in vacuum. Not too surprising to me as I've always thought the main principle of a siphon was the interaction of the fluid inside the tube/pipe.
2. There's such a thing as a flying-droplet syphon. This was more surprising to me, but It seems reasonable that the drop of fluid in the mid chamber would cause enough of a pressure difference to pull fluid up from the higher reservoir.

These show that the siphon can use both on the surrounding pressure and the inter-fluid interactions. My question is if we get rid of both of those would the siphon still function? Will a flying-droplet siphon work in vacuum (both surroundings and the mid chamber)? I assume the answer is no, but I'm hoping someone can direct me to a source that conclusively shows that it doesn't (or does.)

Comment: The liquid would boil when placed in a vacuum.

Comment: Not necessarily, mercury, for instance, can be a liquid in vacuum as long as the temperature is low enough.